# Remove author and date on some posts with conditional tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the Author and Date on posts assigned to a specific category for a site that I'm just started. I thought the following addition to my custom theme's function.PHP file would do the trick. The name of the category is "Funds" and for all other posts not assigned this category I want the Author and Date information to remain.

```
if (is_category('Funds')) {
    remove_action('genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info');
}
```

This code appears to have no affect on the site, and all posts continue to have the author and date information appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Kyle Looks like Wordpress....

Comment: Yes this is Wordpress, and I'm using a custom theme from StudioPress

Answer (score 2):

Try this but replace "Testimonials" with "Funds". Note I have also customised the return from the post info to not show authors etc for any post category.  The below code will effectively remove the post date from any posts with the category "Testimonials" and all but post date from any other post category.

```
/** Customize the post info function */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'post_info_filter' );
function post_info_filter($post_info) {
    if (!is_category('Testimonials')) {
        $post_info = '[post_date]'; // removed by [post_author_posts_link] at [post_time] [post_comments] [post_edit]
    return $post_info;
}}
```

The above code is placed in your child themes functions.php

Answer (score 1):

If you put that code *as-is* into your theme's `functions.php` file it'll run too early; the *"query"* will not have run and thus WordPress won't yet know your category. You need to run your code from a hook that runs after the query.

*Assuming* that `'genesis_post_info'` is in fact the hook you need then this code will *probably* work for you *(I don't have Genesis to test to be sure.)* And yes, you can put this code into your theme's `functions.php` file since it delays running the remove until after `the_posts` hook:

```
add_filter('init','yoursite_the_posts');
function yoursite_the_posts($posts) {// 'the_posts' runs immediately after the query
  if ($wp_the_query === $wp_query && // If first query on a page load
      is_category('Funds')) {        // And if this is the Funds category
    remove_action('genesis_before_post_content', 'genesis_post_info');
  return $posts;                     // Gotta return the posts, they are expected
}
```

Let me know if this works or if not what problems you run into.

### Better Alternate? Custom Post Types for your *"Funds"*

Have you considered using [**Custom Post Types**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128/tips-for-using-wordpress-as-a-cms/187#187) for your Funds instead of shoehorning them into Posts?  I'm guessing you'll get a lot better results if you do.

If you do use a Custom Post Type then these might help you theme them:

- [Create a Widget Area in the Navigation Bar for the Genesis Theme Framework?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/create-a-widget-area-in-the-navigation-bar-for-the-genesis-theme-framework)
- [Using Custom Templates for Custom Post Types with the Genesis Theme Framework?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/456/using-custom-templates-for-custom-post-types-for-the-genesis-theme-framework)

Hope this helps.

-Mike

Comment: nice way of hooking wordpress.se:D

Answer (score 0):

First the answers above helped me very much, but then I realized that the interpreation of the question might be a little off. So my answer is really the solution 'I' was looking for but depending on the original intent of the question might also be what Hamish was looking for as well.

The issue seems to be whether or not to remove the Author and date on posts "In a Category" as opposed to on posts listed in the archive listing of a category.

For example, I wanted (something slightly different) to remove just the date (not the author) but I wanted the date removed on the single post view of that post whenever it happened to be in a category called case studies.  So I used

```
/** Customize the post info function */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'post_info_filter' );
function post_info_filter($post_info) {
if ( in_category('case-studies') ) {
    $post_info = 'By [post_author] [post_edit]'; // removed by [post_author_posts_link] at [post_time] [post_comments] [post_edit]
       return $post_info; 
    }
        else {
        $post_info = '[post_date] By [post_author]  [post_edit]'; // removed by [post_author_posts_link] at [post_time] [post_comments] [post_edit]
           return $post_info;
        }
```

Note I'm using in_category not is_category  :)

It might be possible that Hamish actually wants a hybrid where both the archive listing of all the posts on the category page do not display authors and dates AND the individual posts that happen to be in the category in question do not display the author and date.

In that case my code above would need to be more complex to handle both conditions.

**Simple Edits Conflict**
If you are running the Genesis Simple Edits plugin, that plugin will also trump (run) after the function above.  I haven't yet figured out how/when to hook into this after Simple Edits myself.... (update For starters I simply commented out the post info section of this plugin for now, so that I could keep my post_meta and footers running via simple edits)

Oh and here is the Studio Press tutorial via Brian Gardner on this (little too simplistic for this situation but probably got Hamish started)

http://www.briangardner.com/code/customize-post-info/